# When I'm using URLEncoder for Http GET Request I'm getting proper URL but when I push that code to live or on server I'm getting error

Tags: java, apache, http, url, urlencode

When I'm using `URLEncoder` for Http GET Request I'm getting proper URL but when I push that code to live or on server I'm getting error.

The reason is in live or server more than 3 spaces are converted into `%09` ie. 5 spaces become `+++%09`

```
hmMailDetails.put("content", URLEncoder.encode(sContent.trim(),"UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Sounds more like the actual problem might be that you can not correctly differentiate between a space and a tabulator (because `%09` is the latter) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just i have replaced the %09 with an %20........
String cont = URLEncoder.encode(sContent.trim(),"UTF-8");
hmMailDetails.put("content",cont.replace("+", "%20").replace("%09", "%20"));